# Extract command line from target programmatically in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a very simple `CMakeLists.txt` with a single C++ executable:

```
... set libraries here
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

**Is there a way to extract the command line for compilation of `main` and store it in a cmake variable?**

I was able to find many "target" properties (such as LINK_LIBRARIES and INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES), but not one with the full command line and reconstructing the command line seems to be something very hard.

Note: I know cmake can be verbose an print the command lines when compiling but I want to store this in variable for another purpose (in a `configure_file` command for string replacement in a generated file).

Comment: Sorry why do you need to do this? I don't know what "cmake-configure a file" means

Comment: @hdf89shfdfs I need the variable to be used in the `configure_file` command. (that is what I mean be `cmake-configure`.

Comment: Do you want the compilation of main.cpp or the linking of main?  I don't know how to solve your question, but a person who will may need to know this information.

Comment: @StephenNewell good question. Ideally both, but linking would me more important. For compilation the include directories and the compilation options are the most important.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't be possible at all, but I'm not 100% certain. When generating the project files with CMake you can decide for multiple generators/compilers. It may be possible to extract the info you're looking for from makefiles, but you probobably cannot do this for a Visual Studio project. Furthermore cmake uses 2 phases when setting up the project: one configuration phase reading in the files and setting up data in appropriate data structures and one generating the output files. You're trying to access info computed in the second phase in the first one though.

Comment: @fabian +1 that explains why it is was so difficult to find an answer.

Comment: @fabian do you know if it possible to generate/configure a script that would be able to compile the file?

Comment: The command line interface for cmake should be the same accross platforms and it allows you to specify the target(s) you want to build, so it's definetly possible to generate a cmake script that uses `execute_process` to invoke cmake with the appropriate command line parameters on the build system. If you want to generate a script that given the source file, the script and the compiler would compile the source even without cmake being available on the system: that afaik is nothing cmake provides any features for; You may of course implement the logic on your own, but that wouldn't be trivial.